# protection circuits

Tags: diodes, protection, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help explain how these work?  I know they are missing information,  but I wanted a general idea on how they are meant to function.

1. Why place two diodes facing each other?
2. How does the diode protect against reverse polarity?
3. How does this one work?

I guess I don't understand the diodes to ground and battery etc.  Like if a battery is in reverse does the diode go into reverse breakdown and current runs to the GND?

I would appreciate any help in this subject.

Comment: Are you sure they do work?  Where are you getting these circuits from?  Are these Zener diodes?

Comment: Your circuit looks confusing, the 2 Voltage sources have one node floating, connect them to ground. Even better, use **one** voltage source to draw the supply line. Place the source left of D3, D4 with + on top. The LOAD resistors are missing a connection as well. This kind of protection circuits is used as ESD protection. Google for "ESD protection circuit" to learn more.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a complete circuit, it was meant to show three examples of diodes in circuits used for protection.  I understand how different inputs and outputs change this, but I meant is more as a template of 3 different protection strategies I have seen.  I apologize foe the confusion, and these are normal Silicon diodes.

Comment: Also, I understand the middle one now: Basically, at the node we have a clip (or clamp, I think clamp because we aren't clipping the signal, we are forcing, or clamping, the voltage at that node to be a certain level) at that node preventing the node from go +/- over the threshold we wish to maintain.  ex. if V=4.3V then we have a biased clamp of 5V when the signal is above -.7V and below 5 V.  If we exceed 5V, the current ends up going to the 4.3V battery source and if we go under -.6 V, the current will go to GND through the LOW diode.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to protect and what from. It matters what the impedance of your load is.

Typically if you want to protect the inputs of a device you put two diodes like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDFCEJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the signal V1 goes 0.7V above Vcc D2 will turn on and allow the current to go through D2 and lower the voltage. If it goes 0.7V below ground then D1 will turn on and shunt the current. In this way you can "protect" inputs of devices from voltage.

Back to back diodes only turn on when the reverse breakdown voltage is met, which is in the 10's of volts. The other two circuits don't offer any protection in the context that was given in the original question.

There are also ESD or TVS diodes that protect against large short voltage spikes and turn on when a voltage of hundreds of volts is across their terminals. They shunt ESD spikes which are in the 1000's of volts away from sensitive electronics.

When using diodes watch the thermal ratings, if a current larger than the device can handle or the thermal rating is exceeded then it will destroy the device. Resistors can be used in series to limit current.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the diodes facing each other now.  I apologize about not creating the circuits in context, they were just designs I have seen many times, but without a clear understanding of how they protect devices.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Just did, sorry first time using this site.